# how to prove $(b^m)^\frac{1}{n}=(b^p)^\frac{1}{q}$if $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p}{q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For this question $b>1$, $n>0$, $q>0$; and $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$ are integers.
I tried putting the equations to the power of $n$ and $q$ to cancel out the reciprocal exponent and I also tried to prove that $(b^m)^\frac{1}{n}=b^\frac{m}{n}$. Both attempts have failed and I'm not quite sure what else to try. Any help would vastly appreciated.

Comment: $\left(b^m\right)^\frac{1}{n}=b^\frac{m}{n}$ is a well known rule. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html

Comment: It is but I haven't been able to prove it and its not something i can take for granted in this question.

Comment: This link might help out then http://andrusia.com/math/preliminaries/ExponentiationTheorems.pdf

Comment: The issue with that is that it proves the law if you have an integer as your exterior exponent, but i need a proof for a fraction outer exponent.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the last theorem (H) should do the trick? You then have $a^\frac{m}{n}=\sqrt[n]{a^m} \implies a^\frac{m}{n}=\sqrt[n]{(a^m)} \implies a^\frac{m}{n}=(a^m)^\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Yeah it does my textbook is just doing things weirdly and using this to define rational exponents lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since
$$\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p}{q}$$
you also have:
$$m=n\frac{p}{q}$$

Now, we have:
$$b^m=b^{n\frac{p}{q}}=b^{p\frac{n}{q}}=\left((b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}\right)^{n}$$
So, by applying $n$-th roots, we have:
$$(b^{m})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left((b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}\right)^{n\frac{1}{n}}=(b^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$.

Hope this helped! :)